# Converting Byte Array of a JPEG Image but with wrong extension

Tags: java, image

I am having an image file downloaded as byte array inside my java method. Need to convert this byte array into BufferedImage.

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imagebyteArray);
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpg", new File("/Users/abc/test.jpg"));
```

Above code snippet is used to convert the image byte array and write into jpeg file. But I am getting a zero sized image file.

But issue with the downloaded image. Image is actually JPEG format but the extension is wrong like image.doc

Is it a problem ? , if that is an issue Is there any way to convert the extension of the image (byte array) using java2d , and then convert to BufferedImage?

Comment: How is the `imagebyteArray` been created?  Are there any exceptions been raised? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, this will reduce the guess work and produce better response.

Comment: Why do you need to decode the image to a `BufferedImage` in the first place? Are you planning to change the pixels in any way? If not, it's a lot faster to just write the bytes from `imagebyteArray` directly to disk (and you'll preserve metadata, that is otherwise stripped). Side note, `ImageIO` doesn't care about file names or extensions, just the bytes in the input stream or file. But there's [a lot of JPEGs it can't read](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#jpeg) (or write for that matter).

Comment: I need to resize the image, That's the reason I converted into BufferedImage.